# What is the alternative method or way to use UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior and UseDatabaseNullSemantics in EF Core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm migrating one of my legacy .NET framework application to .NET 6. The legacy application had LINQ to SQL for all the database operations, whereas in the migrated application we are using EF Core 6.

While testing there were few lambda expressions which were not returning the expected result. This is the code:

```
paymentDataContext.Messages.Where(m=>m.InvoiceID==InvoiceID).ToList();
//InvoiceID is nullable int returned from another lambda expression
```

When the `InvoiceId` is null, the SQL generated by my legacy application which uses LINQ to SQL had following where clause:

```
WHERE ([t0].[InvoiceID] = @p0)
```

whereas when the same line is executed in EF Core 6, it generates

```
WHERE [p].[InvoiceID] IS NULL
```

due to which there's difference in the result count.

I want EF Core to behave the same way and return the same result which LINQ to SQL returned using equals (=) operator.

After doing some investigation I found that `UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior` and `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` helped to achieve this behavior, but these methods aren't available in EF Core. Is there any other way or workaround to achieve this?